# What are the options for handling backend for browser-based games which have ongoing calculations?

Tags: c++, backend

I'm getting into the world of browser-based games, and I'm just putting my first into beta stages. Thing is it's a turn-based game, which is very easy to do with a PHP script backend, but as I'm looking forward I'm a bit overwhelmed with choices for development of games that are more real-time.

I'm hesitant to give out exact details of my next project on a public site, so I'll try to describe what I'm looking for here in more ambiguous terms. Basically what I need is some way to handle incoming data from users while also doing background calculations that could possibly be happening many times a second. In a situation like this, it seems folly to have a PHP script setup where scripts are constantly being called an many writes are happening to the database; instead it seems like it would make much more sense to have something like a C++ program running on the server, handling requests and storing values in local memory (until a user logs off, anyway).

It may seem like I have a good idea of what I want, but the thing is I have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to server backends. I know how to make Javascript interact with PHP scripts, and that is the extent of my knowledge. Is a C++ program the best way to go about this? If so, what do I need to get started? (I know some basic C++, but I'm not sure how to get to the point where I can run a program from a server that takes requests). I guess the most ideal thing I could get in this situation is guidance on how I could make a simple interaction where javascript sends up a request to a program on a server which will then do something with the data it receives. I'm usually very good at figuring out things once I have somewhere to start from.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

My advice: if you're looking to actually create that real-time game, and not just looking for a project to learn C++ with (which is an equally worthy, but very different goal), stick with PHP until you actually hit a problem you can't solve. If you architect carefully, you'll be able to replace those parts of the system that need tuning as necessary.

The two charateristics you've identified as requirements for your back-end:

1. A highly interactive session state that you want to keep off the database
2. Background processes (ie, those not triggered by player events over HTTP

I don't see anything in those requirements that takes PHP off the table for the business logic of the game.

For 1) consider things like [redis](http://redis.io/) (via [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis), a popular PHP client). This is your high-performance in-memory data store.

For 2) you could write a completely separate PHP program that talks to the main server just like any other client. If you use redis, it could be talking directly to it. Remember: there's nothing that says PHP has to handle web page requests.

Finally, one other link turned up while researching this - it's old but the code is still available and might be really instructive: [phpsocketdaemon](http://phpsocketdaemon.googlecode.com/files/phpsocketdaemon-1.0.tar.gz) is a "library for writing a daemon in PHP that can handle massive amounts of client and server connections".